# Adjective word that means a person who sets up decisions and plans

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

I'm trying to find the word that is used as an Adjective which means a characteristic of a person who sets up all the plans and decisions.

This word is usually used in relationships when a girl, e.g, is asking the guy to always set up the plan for a date instead of asking her where would she want to go.

This word in a sentence would be like:-
"Stop asking me what i want. I want you to be _______"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. ..maybe like _responsible_?

Comment: Proactive, perhaps ?

Comment: Intuitive, perhaps?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Using your answers, i was able to research the web for the right word. The word i was looking for is "Competent", which means: "having the necessary ability, knowledge, or skill to do something successfully."